# Lenovo laptop not connecting to Wifi properly

Tags: linux, lenovo-laptop

- wifi disconnecting at least every once/20min.
- screen brightness changing on it's own, usually when I change the plug-state (plug or unplug).

I am running this command:

```
sudo echo 150 > /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness
```

to set a nice brightness val.

I've found [this arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight) on backlight useful, but many things go over the top of my head.

**EDIT**

Network card info

> Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE
> 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

**Model**

```
System Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: 80XS
    Version: Lenovo ideapad 320-15ABR
    Serial Number: PF15ZL19
    UUID: eeff1dce-a4e7-11e8-b5f5-8c1645f592e5
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_80XS_BU_idea_FM_ideapad 320-15ABR
    Family: ideapad 320-15ABR
```

Help please?

Comment: Add more info about your laptop(or link to manufacturer's website) and linux distro(kernel version) you are trying.

Comment: @Madhubala done